# Determine which view is the last one that fits with ViewThatFits

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm using `ViewThatFits` in a `ForEach` to display as many items that will fit in the available space. Each item has a `Divider` underneath it. I want the Divider to not be added to the last view that fits. With this setup, I want to remove the Divider from underneath Four since that's the last visible item here. How can that be determined?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            
            ForEach(items, id: \.self) {
                RowView(title: $0, includeBottomDivider: true) //FIXME: How to set to false for last visible item?
                    .layoutPriority(Double(items.count - items.firstIndex(of: $0)!))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
        .background(.fill)
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    let title: String
    let includeBottomDivider: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewThatFits {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(title)
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                
                if includeBottomDivider {
                    Divider()
                }
            }
            
            Color.clear
                .frame(height: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `viewThatFits` with a single view?  You would typically use `viewThatFits` with variations on your view that SwiftUI can choose from.  However you can determine `true/false` for the last element with `items.last == $0`

Comment: Normally that suggestion from @Paulw11 will work great. However, here, it won't lead to the result you want because of the odd usage of `viewThatFits` that @Paulw11 also mentions. The view that shows (where "Four") is the last one is _not_ the last item in the `ForEach`. I'd suggest you use a more _normal_ approach to `ViewThatFits` (your `ForEach` should probably go _inside_ the `ViewThatFits`) and you'll have an easier time.

Comment: If the code can be optimized / more normal while achieving the same result (showing as many items as possible in rows that will fit), I'm def open to that :)

Comment: Right, I didn't appreciate that you are using `viewThatFits` to silently discard some items from your list.  This is quite odd.  I don't think there is any way to get information from `viewThatFits` as to which view it selected.  You would need to provide "n" views to `viewThatFits, one with item 1, one with item 1, a divider and item 2, one with item 1, a divider, item 2, a divider and item 3 and so on.